# Edit admin panel of shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I want to create a tab or button on which promotion can view and there will be a toggle button that turns the promotion on/off as per admin requirement.
But problem is that I'm unable to edit the admin panel of Shopify.

Answer (score 0):

Since a product is the only thing that can be promoted, add a link to the product details screen under more actions labelled "toggle promotion", which will send the ID of the product to an endpoint of your choosing. It works and is the only way to add an action such as this to admin.